# How do I speed up the YOLO v3-v4 inferencing?

Tags: python, tensorrt, tensorrt-python

I run YOLO V3 or YOLO v4 on Jeston Xavier, DNN OpenCV version, It is very slow barely reaches ~ 7- on how to speed up inference?

Comment: Throw more powerful hardware (esp. GPU) at the problem. Online DNN inference is one of the most GPU-intensive problems there is, and if you are using pre-built frameworks, there is little to nothing that can be done on the software-side of things

Comment: due to my application, I need it to run in Xavier. How do you mean by online?

Comment: "Online prediction/inference" is just a way of saying "doing prediction on a live data flow"

Comment: Do you already use tensorrt ? Or why is that tag included. I am not very familiar with the openCV version of yolov3/v4 but if you are not yet using tensorRT this will give a huge performance boost on Jetson hardware.

Comment: @Lukas Thaler Why do you think that? There are a lot of software-side things you can do.  For example using mixed precision for inference, or by using batching.

Comment: with AlexeyAB darknet code and Half-Precision you should reach 18-30 fps on the jetson xavier. TensorRT should be even faster. Did you try opencv with FP16 precision?

Comment: @Micka, by F16, do you mean the OpenCV DNN module?

Comment: set setPreferableTarget to DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16 to use 16 bit floating point arithmetic which should give about 2x speedup compared with standard 32 bit.

Comment: what speed did use achieved in Xavier, using OpenCV-DNN?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you could try to speed up inference:

- Use a smaller network size. Use yolov4-416 instead of yolov4-608 for example.
  This does probably come at the cost of lower accuracy.
- Try converting your network to TensorRT and use mixed precision (FP16 will give a huge performance increase and INT8 even more although then you have to recallibrate your network)

For the last one I would advise following this excellent blog:

[blog](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/tensorrt-yolov4/)

Comment: even with yolov4-608 you should be able to get around 15 fps on the Jetson Xavier.

Comment: I would like to stick to python, I am not a professional at C so is tensorrt python-based?

Comment: Tensorrt has both python and c++ bindings. You can choose.

Comment: You can also use openvino toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the image size in the `.cfg` file:

```
width=416
height=416
```

- Use multiples of 32. (This can affect your accuracy if the objects in your scene are too small).
- And you can crop your input image to keep only the area of interest in a square shape. This helps to keep any small objects from getting compressed too much when you reduce the image size as Yolo will compress your input image to the above `width` and `height` while maintaining the image ratio.

You can also try Yolov3-tiny or Yolov4-tiny, which is a smaller network but this also might affect your accuracy.
(These solutions have been based on my experience. There is always a trade-off between speed and accuracy when dealing with Yolo or other convolutional networks.)